# How to remove the coulmn name in Json in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

For example this is my JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Core"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Moderate"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Remote"
   }
]
```

How can I remove `id` and `name`?

My desired output:

```
[
  {
    "1":"Core"
  },
  {
    "2":"Moderate"
  },
  {
    "3":"Remote"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your output is not valid JSON..

Comment: I assume in the output you mean `[ { "1":"Core" }, { "2":"Moderate" } ]`

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far

Comment: [
  {
    1,
    "Core"
  },
  {
    2,
    "Moderate"
  },
  {
    3,
    "Remote"
  }
]

Comment: Am just fetching the record from DB and its returning with column name i want to remove it help me on this thanks in advance

Comment: [ { "1":"Core" }, { "2":"Moderate" } ] yes i need like this

Comment: give a try to Dictionaty<string, string>

Comment: give a try to Dictionaty<string, string> - Can you please give some example so that it will be easy for me to understand

Comment: You need to provide your actual code in your question.

Comment: First you deserialize it into a list of dictionaries which will have two key values (id and name), then convert this into a new dictionary where id is the key and name is the value and reserialize it, e.g. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(input).ToDictionary(x => x["id"], x => x["name"]))` assuming you are using the NewtonSoft Json library.

Comment: @Shyam https://stackoverflow.com/a/47692141/4594225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
            JArray arr = JArray.Parse(json);

            foreach (var el in arr.ToList())
            {
              var obj = new JObject();
              obj[el["id"].Value<string>()] = el["name"].Value<string>();
              el.Replace(obj);
            }

            var res = arr.ToString();
```

Comment: It throws the error in following line ' var obj = new JObject { [el["id"].Value<string>()] = el["name"].Value<string>() };' Error is invalid initializer member declarator

Comment: maybe indexer initializer was introduced in C# 7.0 and you don't have it. Try to initialize in separate lines. See edit

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var objs = new[]
{
    new {Id = 1, Name = "Core"},
    new {Id = 2, Name = "Moderate"},
    new {Id = 3, Name = "Remote"},
};

var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs);
Console.WriteLine(json1);

var dict = objs.ToDictionary(k => k.Id.ToString(), v => v.Name);

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
Console.WriteLine(json2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could deserialize your json string to an object (MyType) and override the ToString() method

```
public void YourMethod(){
   string json = ...; // your json string 
   List<MyType> myType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyType>>(json);
   var output = string.Join(", ", myType);
}

public class MyType
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name{
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", Id.ToString(), Name);
    }
}
```